# Remove Fragment in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I am having and issue about closing a Fragment.

The reason why I cannot close the Fragment, within the customized Fragment itself, with the following chaining

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);
```

seem to be inheritance, since my customized Fragment inherits from ..

```
extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Android Studio is complaining about the argument in remove(), - "this"

> remove (android.app.Fragment) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to se.fragmenttest.app.myfrafmentest180406.MyFragment)

The strange this is that the same call seem to work from within MainActivity where the Fragment is instanciated.

the whole class

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private View fragmentView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containter, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, containter, false);

    Button button = (Button) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.okbutton_id);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            closeFragment();
        }
    }
    );

    return fragmentView;
}

private void closeFragment() {

    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);
}

}
```

**EDIT:**

code for MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, myFragment, "myfragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(myFragment);


}
```

I tried to remove the fragment in the MainActiviy and there it WORKS. And more - I can put the reference in remove() which I cannot in the Fragment class

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

**(or) use can specify tags**

***Example reference***

You can pop the fragment by name. While adding fragments to the back stack, just give them a name.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragB");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragC");
```

Then in Fragment_C, pop the back stack using the name ie.. `fragB` and include `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`

```
someButtonInC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack ("fragB", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
});
```

Comment: @java  try let me know

Comment: not success :-( .. I've updated my question with code in MainActivity. There fragmentTransaction.remove(myFragment) works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my main computer right now, so can't check...

But i think you need to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` rather than `getFragmentManager()`.

**EDIT**

Now I'm back at my computer I can confirm it is what I said above. It also helps that you have posted your activity code.

In your MainActivity you call:

`MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`

i.e. you call `getSupportFragmentManager()` which is correct, and why it works.

..but in your Fragment you call the standard `getFragmentManager()` as below:

`getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);`

and as the fragment extends a **Support** fragment, when you try and call `this` it can't be found. However, if you change the above line to this:

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);`

`this` will no longer not be found and your code should run.